# Moving an animated / rigged object

Tags: animation

I have a model in Blender that is rigged and animated. The object is not at the origin, and I would like to move it there. I can move the object to the origin by selecting the armature bones and transforming them until the object is at the origin, however, when I start playing an animation or export the file, the object snaps back to its original position (as I'm assuming is defined by the animated key frames). How can I translate an object, animations and all, to the origin without affecting the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it by make your armature an Root bone.
1. Select your Armature
[image]
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*
[image]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> To add new bone. Name it *Root* or whatever you want
[image]
4. Parent your current *Root bone* (which mean if you move it, the whole armature will move with it) to your new *Root bone* you just add.
Select your current *Root bone*, then Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select new *Root bone*.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then select *Keep Offset*
  [image]
5. Now you can move your new bone to the origin and whole armature will go with that.

Comment: I did this, and the same issue happens

Comment: nevermind, I was able to get it working, make sure you use pose mode when making changes to the root bone.

Comment: yeah. i forgot to told you that.